# Ionic throwing error due to google play services after successful build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am going crazy after spending a two days on this...
I have an ionic project that had been working perfectly fine. I updated the ionic to v5 accidentally, which caused havoc and I ended upgrading other things (Android libraries, cordova, npm, etc.) during the process of figuring things out. Although, I ended up fixing the error by downgrading the ionic version, I now have the below error during build:

```
> Transform play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-measurement-sdk-api.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.1.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-ads-lite.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:18.3.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-ads-identifier.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-gass.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:18.3.0) with AarTransform
> Transform legacy-support-v4.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-ads.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-audience.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-audience:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-drive.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-plus.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0) with AarTransform
> Transform play-services-games.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0) with AarTransform
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseResources

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
25 actionable tasks: 25 executed
/home/myuser/Desktop/ionic/MyProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/GameHelper.java:43: error: package com.google.android.gms.games.request does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;
                                           ^
/home/myuser/Desktop/ionic/MyProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/GameHelper.java:174: error: cannot find symbol
    ArrayList<GameRequest> mRequests;
              ^
  symbol:   class GameRequest
  location: class GameHelper
/home/myuser/Desktop/ionic/MyProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/GameHelper.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
    public ArrayList<GameRequest> getRequests() {
                     ^
  symbol:   class GameRequest
  location: class GameHelper
/home/myuser/Desktop/ionic/MyProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/GameHelper.java:714: error: cannot find symbol
            mRequests = Games.Requests
                             ^
  symbol:   variable Requests
  location: class Games
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/myuser/Desktop/ionic/MyProject/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

and below is my platforms/android/project.properties

```
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.3=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+
cordova.system.library.6=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
```

I saw several posts that talk about providing a specific version for the play-services-games so I provided versions based on this page https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. However, it did not help. If I need to provide specific version, what should I provide?

The annoying thing is that this code was working perfectly fine yesterday till I messed up something...

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.3 (/home/myuser/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/myuser/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.12.1
   OS                : Linux 4.18
```

I'd be grateful if you could provide a pointer on the issue.

Many thanks,

Doug

Comment: GameRequest class does not exist in the play services anymore. it was deprecated in 2017. thus you should get that dependency to the originally setup version as well... this is the latest version: com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0

Comment: Hi emirc, many thanks for your answer. Could you please help me out on how how to do that? Do I just put the version number in project.properties for com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0? Or do I need to put version numbers for everything? Or do I do something else? When I look to do logs, it looks like the version was already 19.0.0 (> Transform play-services-games.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0) with AarTransform) but do I need to hardcode this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and as emirc mentioned this boils down to the November 19 release of com.google.android.gms:play-services-games deprecating Real-time and Turn-based multiplayer APIs. See: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

In my case the dependency is pulled by the artberri/cordova-plugin-play-games-services, and if I refer to your error log it seems to be the same for you. We'll have to stick to version 18.0.1 of the dependency until this plugin is updated, which is easily done by setting the ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_GAMES_VERSION when adding it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-services --variable APP_ID=<...> --variable ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_GAMES_VERSION=18.0.1
```